# Localization laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, localization, laravel-5.5

I have been trying to update language for the website.

Controller

```
public function getUpdateLanguage(Request $request) {
        $request_data = $request->all();
         \Session::put('locale', $request_data['language']);
        return redirect()->back();
}
```

Middleware:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 { 
    if ( \Session::has('locale')) {
        \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
    }
    return $next($request);
 }
```

But the true block for `if ( \Session::has('locale'))` never executes and the language is always 'en' and never updates. It works fine if I try

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 { 

     \App::setLocale('arabic');

    return $next($request);
 }
```

kernel:

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
    ];
```

Localization is my middleware. The language update controller method redirects to home:

```
public function getIndex() {
        return view('frontend.home');
}
```

Can someone please guide me where is the session value being cleared or if I am doing it wrong and there is a better way?

Comment: Please put `dump(session('locale'));` before `return redirect()->back();`. Also put the same code as the first line of `handle` method and show the results.

Comment: it returns ''arabic' for dump and adding the code of middleware in controller still gives me 'en'

Comment: could you please show us your kernel??

Comment: @Sohel0415 updated

Comment: add this to your middleware `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` before localization

Comment: or use `$request->session()->exists('locale')`

Comment: add to kernel you mean? @Sohel0415

Comment: added in kernel, and it is working! please post it as an answer @Sohel0415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to your `middleware` array in `kernel.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I am glad too that it helps :)

Comment: Hey again, I have a query. After adding the StartSession to middleware, when my forms are being validated and redirected back to views, the $errors are empty. Have I messed up or is there something I could do about it?

Comment: did you use 'withErrors()'?? when you redirect

Comment: yes.. if i remove StartSession then I get to see errors.. Else the $errors is empty

Comment: show us your controller please where you want to achieve this??

Comment: it has $request->validate([ 'first-name'      => 'required', 'last-name'       => 'required', ]); for validation and other processing stuff

Comment: use Auth; use Hash; use Illuminate\Http\Request; and models. nothing else

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that

**Middleware :**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 { 
    App::setLocale(
        $request->session()->has('locale') ? 
        $request->session()->get('locale') : 
        App::getLocale()
    );

    return $next($request);
 }
```