# StartSession middleware clearing validate errors

Tags: php, laravel, session, error-handling, localization

I was working with localization and had to add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to my kernel.

My previous question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48607759/6808043).

But now my `$errors` is always empty and the errors don't show up in view.

I also tried adding  `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,` after StartSession to my kernel but the errors are still empty.

Controller :

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {
        $request_data = $request->all();
        $request->validate([
          'first-name'      => 'required',
          'last-name'       => 'required',
        ]);
        //other processing stuff
}
```

kernel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

I read errors like this `{{ $errors->first('first-name') }}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version you are using ?

Comment: @C2486 Laravel 5.5

Comment: Do you have included this `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession` ?

Comment: @C2486 yes after StartSession

Comment: @C2486 Also if i remove them both, the errors show up but localization doesn't work and stays to default language

Comment: Can you post code from your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class please?

Comment: @NikolaGavric Updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are adding `StartSession` and `ShareErrorsFromSession` into a wrong variable, they are not alone `HTTP` middlewares, but rather features of a certain group of middleware, for example.

Web is a middleware group which includes various smaller middleware's which enrich further usable features which evolve around `Request`, like using `Cookie`, `Session`, `CsrfToken`, etc.

Try removing `StartSession` and `ShareErrorsFromSession` from `$middleware` variable.

**EDIT:** Also show us your `Localization.php` code, thanks

Comment: @MehravishTemkar I suppose removing `StartSession` and `ShareErrorsFromSession` from `$middleware` didn't resolve your issue?

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining it right, I had all the errors show up before I added StartSession and ShareErrorsFromSession to $middleware. I had to add StartSession for localization (check the link of previous question). What should I do to make them both work

Comment: Did you by any chance forgot to **import** `Session` facade in your `Localization` file?

Comment: i have 'use Session;' in Localization.

Comment: change that to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164855/discussion-between-mehravish-temkar-and-nikola-gavric).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding `StartSession` class then `Localization` class in `$middlewareGroups` `web` array and not in `$middleware`
because if you put it in `$middleware` (executed every HTTP request) the old session will be removed then create a new session.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I did as @NikolaGavric suggested